# Python: Force minio throw error on connection error while (f)putting

Tags: python, minio

I want the minio-client to throw an error if a connection error occurs while putting data to the minio-server.
It correctly returns an error when setting up a connection and the server is down. But if I disconnect the network while uploading (putting). The python process will stay open 'forever'.

What I want is that it returns an error after for example a timeout of 60 seconds.
I just can't find anything like it in any documentation.

My (working) code simplified:

```
from minio import Minio

client = None
bucket = 'testbucket'

def connect():
    print(f"Creating MinioClient")
    global client
    client = Minio(
        '10.0.0.1:9000',
        access_key='myaccesskey',
        secret_key='mysecretkey',
        secure=False
    )

def createBucket():
    global client
    global bucket
    print(f"Making bucket '{bucket}' if not exists")
    found = client.bucket_exists(bucket)
    if not found:
        client.make_bucket(bucket)
    else:
        print(f"Bucket '{bucket}' already exists")


def putFile():
    """ Upload data """
    print("Uploading the file with fput")

    global client
    global bucket

    objectname = 'ReallyBigFile'
    filepath = '/home/jake/4GBfile.bin'

    try:
        result = client.fput_object(
            bucket,
            objectname,
            filepath,
        )
    except IOError as err:
        print(err)

    print("Created {0} object; etag: {1}, version-id: {2}".format(result.object_name, result.etag, result.version_id))


connect()
createBucket()
putFile()
```

Anybody an idea how I can force minio to exit fputting on a connection-error?

Already tried setting up the connection like this: No success:

```
client = Minio(
    '10.0.0.1:9000',
    access_key='myaccesskey',
    secret_key='mysecretkey',
    secure=False,
    http_client=urllib3.poolmanager.PoolManager(
        timeout=1,
        retries=urllib3.Retry(
            total=3,
            backoff_factor=0.2,
            status_forcelist=[500, 502, 503, 504]
        )
    )
```

Some research showed that Minio in fact is capable of recognizing a connection loss while uploading. It turns out it really has to do with the python client or my implementation of it.
Test with the command line tool mc:
The first session is a stable connection and the second is disconnected during upload.
[image: Disconnection recognized]